# Python Inserting Json and updating mongodb using pymongo

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

```
  "event_location": "San Jose",
  "event_type": "Party",
  "source_type": [
    "COMPANY",
    "CONSUM"
  ],
  "device": [
    {          
      "name": "DJ",
      "date_order": "20210120",
      "manufacturer_country": "USA",

    }
  ],
  "problems": [
    "Material Rupture"
  ],
  "zip_code": "",
  
  "sum_text": [
    {
      "sum_text_key": "220229361",
      "text_type_code": "Additional Manufacturer Narrative",
      "text": "A REVIEW OF THE DEVICE HISTORY RECORD HAS BEEN INITIATED."
    },
    {
      "sum_text_key": "220229362",
      "text_type_code": "Description of Event or Problem",
      "text": "DEVICE REPORTED RIGHT SIDE RUPTURE."
    }
  ],
}, {
  "event_location": "New York",
  "event_type": "Baby Shower",
  "source_type": [
    "COMPANY",
    "CONSUM"
  ],
  "device": [
    {          
      "name": "Musical Band",
      "date_order": "20210120",
      "manufacturer_country": "USA",

    }
  ],
  "problems": [
    "Material Rupture"
  ],
  "zip_code": "",
  
  "sum_text": [
    {
      "sum_text_key": "220229361",
      "text_type_code": "Additional Manufacturer Narrative",
      "text": "A REVIEW OF THE DEVICE HISTORY RECORD HAS BEEN INITIATED."
    },
    {
      "sum_text_key": "220229362",
      "text_type_code": "Description of Event or Problem",
      "text": "DEVICE REPORTED RIGHT SIDE RUPTURE."
    }
  ],
}, {
  "event_location": "Boston",
  "event_type": "Wedding",
  "source_type": [
    "COMPANY",
    "CONSUM"
  ],
  "device": [
    {          
      "name": "Soft Music Band",
      "date_order": "20210120",
      "manufacturer_country": "USA",

    }
  ],
  "problems": [
    "Material Rupture"
  ],
  "zip_code": "",
  
  "sum_text": [
    {
      "sum_text_key": "220229361",
      "text_type_code": "Additional Manufacturer Narrative",
      "text": "A REVIEW OF THE DEVICE HISTORY RECORD HAS BEEN INITIATED."
    },
    {
      "sum_text_key": "220229362",
      "text_type_code": "Description of Event or Problem",
      "text": "DEVICE REPORTED RIGHT SIDE RUPTURE."
    }
  ],
}  ]}
```

I have the above json array and want to dump this to mongo db. With certain condition but when I try to insert it I either get a duplicate collection key error or keyerror "_id"

```
db = client["music"]

json = {...data here}

for event in json['results']:
    for device in event['device']:
        name= device['name']
        other_name = ['DJ','Band','String','Home']
        list_of_collections = db.list_collection_names()
        for n in other_name: 
            # When the db is completely empty
            if len(n) ==0:
               collection = db[n] # create a collection with this name
               collection.insert_one(event)
             else:
                 for collection_name in list_of_collections:
                     if n in collection_name:
                        # find the matching collection in list of collection and update it 
                         collection = db[collection_name] 
                         collection.update({'_id': event['_id']},event,upsert=True)
                      else:
                           collection = db[n]
                           collection.insert_one(event)
```

I think i am missing something in the last for loop. I am also getting key error "_id"" in the collection.update line when I am trying to update the db.

E11000 duplicate key error collection: event_tb.DJ index: id dup key: { _id: ObjectId('608c37fb5806d865763c6f58')

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the error you are getting.

Comment: E11000 duplicate key error collection: event_tb.DJ index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('608c37fb5806d865763c6f58')